# PostgreSQL Aggregate groups with limit performance

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I'm a newbie in PostgreSQL. Is there a way to improve execution time of the following query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.url,
       (SELECT array_agg(p.url)
        FROM (
            SELECT url
            FROM pages
            WHERE site_id = s.id ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5
        ) as p
       ) as last_pages
FROM sites s
```

I havn't found how to insert `LIMIT` clause into aggregate call, as ordering.

There are indexes by `created` (`timestamp`) and `site_id` (`integer`) in table `pages`, but the foreign key from `sites.id` to `pages.site_id` is absent, unfortunately. The query is intented to return a list of sites with sublists of 5 most recently created pages.

PostgreSQL version is 9.1.5.

Comment: It's often helpful if you explain what the query is supposed to do and give some general information about the data - tables, relationships, etc. Please also specify your PostgreSQL version in all questions as that can affect available options - and finally, show `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output. See the info page of [tag:postgresql-performance].

Comment: Best to edit your question to add the info. Remember to read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: In addition to Craig's links: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Answer (score 3):

You need to start by thinking like the database management system.  You also need to think very carefully about what you are asking from the database.

Your fundamental problem here is that you likely have a very large number of separate indexing calls happening here when a sequential scan may be quite a bit faster.  Your current query gives very little flexibility to the planner because of the fact that you have subqueries which must be correlated.

A much better way to do this would be with a view (inline or not) and a window function:

```
   SELECT s.id, s.name, s.url, array_agg(p.url)
     FROM sites s
     JOIN (select site_id, url, 
                  row_number() OVER (partition by site_id order by created desc) as num
             from pages) p on s.id = p.site_id
    WHERE num <= 5;
```

This will likely change a very large number of index scans to a single large sequential scan.

Comment: my problem was how to do a limit (using a variable) in a complex aggregate function and this solved it wonderfully. I think this should be forced as correct answer.